# Recurrence For Running Time Of A Recursive Insertion Sort

Tags: c, relation, recurrence, insertion-sort

Currently, I was assigned to write a recursive version of the insertion sort algorithm. And I did that. In fact, here is that:

```
void recursiveInsertionSort(int* inputArray, int p, int q)
{
  while (q > p)
  { 
     recursiveInsertionSort(inputArray, p, q-1);
     if (inputArray[q-1] > inputArray[q])
     {
         int temp = inputArray[q];
         int temp2 = inputArray[q-1];
         inputArray[q] = temp2;
         inputArray[q-1] = temp;
         q--;
     }
  }
}
```

My problem is twofold. First, i'm not sure if the recurrence relation I came up with is right. I came up with

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n^2)
```

as my recurrence relation. Is that right? I'm bouncing between that and just

```
T(n) = T(n^2)
```

Second, I am supposed to use algebra to prove that

```
f(n) = ((n+1)n / 2)
```

solves that recurrence relation. Which i'm having a real tough time doing because A. I'm not sure if my recurrence is right and B. I am sometimes awful at math in general.

Any help on any of the issues would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Alright I managed to figure it out with the help of a math professor :P I'm going to leave this up here so that others know how to do it. Someone should copy this as an answer :D

So the recurrence relation for this should be T(n) = T(n-1) + n and not what I originally had, that was the main problem. Why? Well its the time it takes to do the recursive backtravel which is n-1 since if you were to go to n, you would have only one element and that's arleady sorted. Plus the time it takes to do one insertion or one actual sort.

The reason that that is n is because when you get down there, you are checking one number against every number before it which happens to be n amount of times.

Now how do you show that that function f(n) solves the T(n)?

Well we know that f(n) solves T(n). So that means you can do this:

```
We know that f(n) is equal to (n(n+1))/2 . So if T(n) is equal to T(n-1) + n, that means we take away 1 from every n in f(n) and then plug that into T(n).

That gives us T((n+1-)n-1)/2)) + n . That simplifies to T((n(n-1)/2) + n. Take that + n thats out there and multiply it by 2/2 to be able to have it all over a common denominator. Giving you (n^2 - n + 2n)/2 . Simplifies down to ((n^2) + n)/2 which further simplifies to, if you factor out an n, (n(n+1))/2. Which is f(n).
```

Woo!

Comment: Where does the squaring come from?

Comment: Does this function terminate when the input is already sorted? It seems to me `inputArray[q-1]` will be less than `inputArray[q]`, and q will stay the same for another loop of doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: In my brain it does. The Q > P check should terminate the function when it's all sorted since q is being decremented each time it's called. I think anyways, if i'm wrong, let me know. I'm caught up with trying to figure out this recurrence relation and function thing that I may have overlooked something.

Comment: @neojb1989 The problem I see with the code is the case where q is *not* decremented. Either the sorted case, or the opposite will leave q the same (since `q--` is inside an `if` block), so the loop will just keep on repeating for the same q value indefinitely.

Comment: Problem is, just leaving it like this means the question stays open. You should eventually use the Answer button below to answer your own question so that it closes, delete the question so that people don't keep ending up here, or hope that other people flag it closed to clean up for you.